# SSL and MAC (Message Authentication Code) headers

Tags: ssl, openssl, httpservice

I need to encrypt all communication between the server and client by using MAC headers. Is it possible for someone to explain how exactly the MAC header works with the SSL mechanism and where can it be seen ?

I need to verify if the mac headers are present.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such option in JSSE either. There are MACs on every TLS/SSL record, but in the trailer, not the header. Ask them what they are talking about.